# What's a better word for "evoke" in the phrase "evoke a realization"?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What's a better word for "evoke" in the phrase "evoke a realization"?

The context is a technical article about a catch-all module, and the wording is:

"A glance at the feature set <evokes> the unsettling realization that this module was used as a singular dumping ground for all kinds of varying features"

Evoke doesn't capture the meaning, something more like inspires, conjures, can't quite get it. And what process do people use to determine these things?

Comment: I would seriously consider _prompt_ as a verb in that situation.

Comment: And then it hit me like a ton of bricks...

Comment: It's a pretty common phrase.  Could you say what you don't like about it, and provide a context?

Comment: Sven Yargs has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @SvenYargs Add this as a response and I will accept it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is the verb **prompt**. Here is the relevant entry in *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003):

> **prompt** *vt* **1 :** to move to action : INCITE **2 :** to assist (one acting or reciting) by suggesting  or saying the next words of something forgotten or imperfectly learned: CUE **3 :** to serve as the inciting cause of {evidence *prompting* an investigation}

The third definition here has the meaning you're looking for, I think.

Answer (score 1):

> A glance at the feature set **leads to** the unsettling realization that this module was used as a singular dumping ground for all kinds of varying features

But really the whole sentence still feels complicatedly written. How about:

> Looking at the feature set reveals that this module was purposefully used as a dumping ground for disparate features.

Answer (score 0):

Better is a relative concern.  I'm guessing you don't like *evoke* because it sounds a bit snooty, but I'm only guessing.

> Cause a realization.

The meaning isn't identical but it won't make you sound like you swallowed a dictionary.

You may wish to simply reword as an idiom:

> - That made me realize
> - That caused me to realize
> - I came to realize
> - I came to the realization that
> - That made me come to the realization that

Answer (score 0):

The question's been bumped, so I'm going to suggest [**"bring"**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bring):

> Cause (someone or something) to be in a particular state or condition (-- Oxford Dictionaries Online)

*"A glance at the feature set brings the unsettling realization..."*

I do like "prompts", but for me it's closer to "encourages" - i.e the "unsettling realization" may not happen. My feeling is that the OP wants the reaction to seem inevitable, and immediate.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with the somewhat flowery term "**dawned**"

> [**dawn**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/dawn) - Become evident to the mind; be perceived or understood

For example: I stayed up all night wondering where the sun had gone, and then it **dawned** on me.

Comment: But you have replaced more than just the word the OP wanted replaced.